# getting error unable to recognize "ingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am taking a helm chart class and the 1st lab creates a pod, service and ingress.  I am relatively new to k8s and I am running on minikube.  The pod and service get created without issue; however the ingress.yaml file gives the following error:

**unable to recognize "ingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1**

I am guessing something is obsolete in the ingress.yaml file but have no idea how to fix it.  here's the class repo:

```
https://github.com/phcollignon/helm3
```

here's the pod frontend.yaml :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: phico/frontend:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: frontend
        ports:
        - name: frontend
          containerPort: 4200
```

here's the frontend_service.yaml :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: frontend
  name: frontend
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 4200
  selector:
    app: frontend
```

Here's the problem file ingress.yaml :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: guestbook-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: frontend.minikube.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
  - host: backend.minikube.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 80%
```

Here's minikube version (kubectrl version) :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.5", GitCommit:"5c99e2ac2ff9a3c549d9ca665e7bc05a3e18f07e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-16T08:38:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.1", GitCommit:"86ec240af8cbd1b60bcc4c03c20da9b98005b92e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-16T11:34:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

I changed the ingress.yaml file to use
`apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1:`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: guestbook-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: frontend.minikube.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: backend.minikube.local
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend
            port:
              number: 80
```

now I am getting an error:

**error: error parsing ingress.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 17: mapping values are not allowed in this context**

line 17 is the second "paths:" line.

Again, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ingress spec `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` has deprecated. You can update it to `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`

Second question:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: guestbook-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: frontend.minikube.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix  
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: backend.minikube.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: i changed it but now i am encountering some other issue:

Comment: I put the new error in the description of the problem above.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: See the updated answer. If you have further question you need to mark this as answer and start a new question. On stackoverflow one question one answer to be follow.

Comment: I <3 U, this help me a lot

Comment: Please refer K8S docs for latest update to API Version & syntax: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/